Confusion about variance statistic in OMC
Adding context, I'm studying Markov Chain Monte Carlo and I'm currently on Ordinary Monte Carlo or Independent Monte Carlo where I have confusion about what it states as estimator of "Variance in the CLT".

Let \begin{align}\mu=E(g(X))\end{align} be an expression that cannot be solved analytically. However, we can simulate $(X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots)$ which are IID variables having same distribution as $X$. So if we consider, $$Y_i=g(X_i)$$ which will have mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2=Var(g(X))$ and $\hat\mu_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$, we would have according to CLT,$$\hat\mu_n\approx N(\mu,n^{-1}\sigma^2)$$

Then here is the excerpt that I am confused about,

The variance of the CLT can be estimated by $$\hat\sigma_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(g(X_i)-\hat\mu_n)$$

which confuses me as I thought the unbiased estimator for variance would have to be the following sample statistic $$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(g(X_i)-\hat\mu_n)$$.
Reference: page 7, Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo
